# Is there any cheat sheet for vim-latex mappings?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I wonder if anyone knows any list of "magical words" such as

```
vaw`em
```

which changes the format to italics of the current word for vim-latex different than this [one](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/vimlatexqrc.pdf)

Comment: A better link to the cheat sheet you link to is http://michaelgoerz.net/refcards/#latexsuite . It also includes the source file.

Comment: @NN: This seems like it should be an answer to me.

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled upon this one today, as also already posted above.

http://michaelgoerz.net/refcards

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX Suite's help provides quite a bit of information of such mappings. Quoting from the help file

```
Changing commands                                           *ls_3_2_3* *ls_a_br*
                                                             *changing-commands*

                                                          *ls-vmap-f7* *ls_a_dY*
In both insert and normal mode <S-F7> will find out if you are presently within
an environment and then prompt you with a list of commands to change it to.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Font Mappings                                     *ls_3_3* *ls_a_bs* *font-maps*

These mappings insert font descriptions such as: \textsf{<++>}<++> with the
cursor left in place of the first placeholder [|ls_a_eD|] (the <++> characters).

Mnemonic:
1. first letter is always F (F for font)

2. next 2 letters are the 2 letters describing the font.

Example: Typing FEM in insert-mode expands to \emph{<++>}<++>.

Just like environment mappings, you can visually select an area and press `sf to
have it enclosed in: \textsf{word} or  >
    {\sffamily
    line
    }
depending on character-wise or line-wise selection.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Section Mappings                                              *ls_3_4* *ls_a_bt*
                                                              *section-mappings*

These maps insert LaTeX sections such as:  >
    \section{<++>}<++>
etc. Just as in the case of environments and fonts, can be enclosed with a
visual selection. The enclosing is not sensitive to character or line-wise
selection.

Mnemonic: (make your own!)  >
    SPA for part
    SCH for chapter
    SSE for section
    SSS for subsection
    SS2 for subsubsection
    SPG for paragraph
    SSP for subparagraph


Example: SSE in insert mode inserts  >
    \section{<++>}<++>
If you select a word or line and press ,se, then you get  >
    \section{section name}
The menu item in Tex-Environments.Sections have a sub-menu called 'Advanced'.
Choosing an item from this sub-menu asks a couple of questions (whether you want
to include the section in the table of contents, whether there is a shorter name
for the table of contents) and then creates a more intelligent template.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Greek Letter Mappings                                         *ls_3_5* *ls_a_bu*
                                                         *greek-letter-mappings*

Lower case

`a through `z expand to \alpha through \zeta.Upper case:

  >
    `D = \Delta
    `F = \Phi
    `G = \Gamma
    `Q = \Theta
    `L = \Lambda
    `X = \Xi
    `Y = \Psi
    `S = \Sigma
    `U = \Upsilon
    `W = \Omega
NOTE: LaTeX does not support upper case for all greek alphabets.


Just like other Latex-Suite mappings, these mappings are not created using the
standard imap command. Thus you can type slowly, correct using <BS> etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Auc-Tex Key Bindings                                          *ls_3_6* *ls_a_bv*
                                                              *auc-tex-mappings*

These are simple 2 key expansions for some very commonly used LaTeX elements:

  >
    `^   Expands To   \Hat{<++>}<++>
    `_   expands to   \bar{<++>}<++>
    `6   expands to   \partial
    `8   expands to   \infty
    `/   expands to   \frac{<++>}{<++>}<++>
    `%   expands to   \frac{<++>}{<++>}<++>
    `@   expands to   \circ
    `0   expands to   ^\circ
    `=   expands to   \equiv
    `\   expands to   \setminus
    `.   expands to   \cdot
    `*   expands to   \times
    `&   expands to   \wedge
    `-   expands to   \bigcap
    `+   expands to   \bigcup
    `(   expands to   \subset
    `)   expands to   \supset
    `<   expands to   \le
    `>   expands to   \ge
    `,   expands to   \nonumber
    `~   expands to   \tilde{<++>}<++>
    `;   expands to   \dot{<++>}<++>
    `:   expands to   \ddot{<++>}<++>
    `2   expands to   \sqrt{<++>}<++>
    `|   expands to   \Big|
    `I   expands to   \int_{<++>}^{<++>}<++>
(again, notice the convenient place-holders)

In addition the visual mode macros are provided:

  >
    `(  encloses selection in \left( and \right)
    `[  encloses selection in \left[ and \right]
    `{  encloses selection in \left\{ and \right\}
    `$  encloses selection in $$ or \[ \] depending on characterwise or
                                          linewise selection


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Diacritics                                                    *ls_3_7* *ls_a_bw*
                                                            *diacritic-mappings*

These mappings speed up typing European languages which contain diacritic
characters such as a-umlaut etc.  >
    +<l>     expands to \v{<l>}
    =<l>     expands to \'{<l>}
where <l> is an alphabet.

  >
    +}       expands to \"{a}
    +:       expands to \^{o}
Latex-Suite also ships with smart backspacing [|ls_a_dZ|] functionality which
provides another convenience while editing languages with diacritics.

NOTE: Diacritics are disabled by default in Latex-Suite because they can
      sometimes be a little too intrusive. Moreover, most European users can
      nowadays use font encodings which display diacritic characters directly
      instead of having to rely on Latex-Suite's method of displaying
      diacritics.

      Set the g:Tex_Diacritics [|ls_a_df|] variable to enable diacritics.



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BibTeX Shortcuts                                              *ls_3_8* *ls_a_bx*
                                                               *bibtex-bindings*

Latex-Suite provides an easy way of entering bibliographic entries. Four
insert-mode mappings: BBB, BBL, BBH and BBX are provided, all of which
essentially act in the same manner. When you type any of these in insert-mode,
you will get a prompt asking you to choose a entry type for the bibliographic
entry.

When you choose an entry type, a bibliographic entry template will be inserted.
For example, if you choose the option 'book' via the map BBB, then the following
template will be inserted:  >
    @BOOK{<+key+>,
        author = {<++>},
        editor = {<++>},
        title = {<++>},
        publisher = {<++>},
        year = {<++>},
        otherinfo = {<++>}
    }<++>


<+key+> will be highlighted in select-mode and you can type in the bib-key.
After that you can use <Ctrl-J> to navigate to successive locations in the
template and enter new values.

BBB inserts a template with only the fields mandatorily required for a given
entry type. BBL inserts a template with commonly used extra options. BBH inserts
a template with more options which are not as commonly used. BBX inserts a
template with all the fields which the entry type supports.

NOTE: Mnemonic
      --------
      B for Bibliographic entry, L for Large entry, H for Huge entry, and X
      stands for all eXtras.
```

Comment: How do you open this help page in vim?

Comment: @sjdh I know I'm late on this: `:help latex-suite.txt`