# Remove a \textit{} or \emph{} in Vim with vim-latex (LaTeX-Suite)

Tags: vim, vim-latex

Thanks to this [SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32483/31839) I now know that I can emphasise the highlighted word with `` `em ``.

Is there a way to *remove* the `\emph{}` from a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13462522) on Stack Overflow. The accepted answer by [Peter Rincker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438329/) is:

> If you have [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) by Tim Pope this might do
>
> ```
> nmap <silent> dsa ds}dF\
> ```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. It's a pain that there're two websites really isn't it? Things tend to fall between two stools.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative Plugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)

provides mapping in the spirit of [*surround.vim*](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround)

`dsc` - delete surrounding command
`dse` - delete surrounding environment

Plugin is currently (09/2015) maintained and actively developed in 2015.